# Storing data with GM_getvalue in incognito mode

Tags: javascript, tampermonkey

Is it possible to save data permanently with GM_getValue in incognito Mode (chrome) ?

I saw suggestions that  I can enable "Store data in Incognito" under Tampermonkey Security settings. But that particular setting seems missing. I also saw screenshot from others where it was visible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tampermonkey on Chrome:

1. Data stored in *Incognito Mode* is lost when incognito is left.
2. I saw no Tampermonkey setting that would change that (Tampermonkey 4.8).
3. [Google Chrome does not want extensions saving data in incognito mode](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview#incognito):

   > Incognito mode promises that the window **will leave no tracks**. When dealing with data from incognito windows, **extensions should honor this promise**. If an extension normally saves browsing history, don't save history from incognito windows. However, extensions can store *setting* preferences (only) from any window, incognito or not.

Tampermonkey on Firefox:

1. `GM_setValue` data stored in/from *Private Windows* is preserved.
2. I saw no Tampermonkey setting that would change that (Tampermonkey 4.9.5921).